# Reduce size of select option in jqgrid

Tags: css, jqgrid

I have a country code selection drop down in a JQGrid but few of entry in country code is very big and the drop down width is getting increased. Using CSS I was able to reduce the size but the option list size is same it is not getting reduced. Can any one let me know how I can reduce the option list size or make the entry in option as multi-line?

[image]

Comment: what CSS you used, can you share

Comment: Is this help you? http://jsbin.com/jofiyazi/1/edit

Comment: I wanted to change only specific selects size hence I used following CSS. `#TblGrid_subscriberList select {width: 126px;}`. But as you can see in the image the option list which is shown after clicking the drop down is going out of the form. I want to reduce that size.

Answer (score 0):

That's because some of the country's name are very long. The dropdown list will stretch its width to accommodate those long names. The first solution that comes to mind is to have a function that shortens the countries.